# Quote id is empty when inserting multiple records into cart in magento2

Tags: magento2, addtocart, ajax, query

I am adding product to cart from ajax by passing product id

Here is my controller code.

```
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
class AddItems extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

protected $formKey;   
protected $cart;
protected $product;
protected $_resource;
protected $checkoutSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->product = $product;     
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;   
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{ 
   $selectedItems = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selectedItems');      
    $selectedItems = explode(",",$selectedItems);
    try{
    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    foreach ($selectedItems as $key => $selectedItem) {

        $params = array(
            'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
            'product_id' => $selectedItem, //product Id
            'qty'   =>1 //quantity of product                
        );
        $_product = $this->product->create()->load($selectedItem);       
         $item = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($_product );
        if($item){          
            $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();                   
            $quote->updateItem($item->getId(), array( 'qty' => 1));
            $quote->save();
        }else{                  
            $this->cart->addProduct($_product , $params);
        }
      $customPrice = 1000;
      $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();
      $quoteId = $quote->getId();   
      $productItem = $this->getProductQuote($_product );                
      $productItem->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
      $productItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
      $productItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);     
     $insertProductSql = "INSERT INTO custom_table (quote_id, product_id) VALUES ('$quoteId', '$_product->getId()')";
        $connection->query($insertProductSql);
    }
        $this->cart->save();
        $status = 1;
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addException($e,__('%1', $e->getMessage()));
        $status = 0;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('error.'));
        $status = 0;
    }
    $result = array();
    $result['status'] = $status;
    $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
    $resultJson->setData($result);
    return $resultJson;
    }
   public function getConnection()
   {
    $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    return $connection;
    }
  public function getProductQuote($product) {
    $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();        
    $cartItems = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);        
    return $cartItems;
   }
 }
```

Quote id is not getting retrieved for me, always it is empty.

I need to add both the items to the cart with insert query for custom table,

products are adding to the cart successfully,but quote id storing as null inside my custom table

**Note: I am setting custom price for each product.**

Can anyone look into this, where i am wrong please?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: print your sql query (`echo $insertProductSql `) in browser and then check if you are getting the quote id in your insert query or not.

Comment: @DineshYadav, not its not returned quoteid after printing it.

Comment: Paste your query here which you printed in the browser.

Comment: @DineshYadav, here is my result,
INSERT INTO custom_table (quote_id, product_id) VALUES ('','3')

Comment: Have you tried this?

    `$this->cart->save();
    $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();
    $quoteId = $quote->getId();`

Comment: @DineshYadav, you mean cart->save() inside forach()?

Comment: Yes, inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93582/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-dinesh-yadav).

Comment: @jafarpinjar your code seems right, can you try to dump `$quoteId = $quote->getId();`and check whaty you got

Comment: Hi, @magefrms, its empty, I am getting null

Comment: @magefms, it is empty only when freshly added product to cart

Answer (score 2):

you can use same logic as magento doing for related product

if you see below file

```
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php#L105
if (!empty($related)) {
            $this->cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
        }
```

if you check that model

```
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Cart.php#L419


foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
            $productId = (int)$productId;
            if (!$productId) {
                continue;
            }
            $product = $this->_getProduct($productId);
            if ($product->getId() && $product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
                try {
                    $this->getQuote()->addProduct($product);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $allAdded = false;
                }
            } else {
                $allAvailable = false;
            }
        }

        if (!$allAvailable) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__("We don't have some of the products you want."));
        }
        if (!$allAdded) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__("We don't have as many of some products as you want."));
        }
    }
```

you need to use same logic for you.

for you:-

```
 $selectedItems = explode(",",$selectedItems);
foreach ($selectedItems as $key=>$selectedItem) {
    $productId = (int)$productId;
    if (!$productId) {
        continue;
    }
    $product = $this->_getProduct($selectedItem);
    if ($product->getId() && $product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
        $this->cart->getQuote()->addProduct($product);
    } 
}

$this->cart->save();
```

Comment: hi @Sunil Patel, is it possible to update for my question, that will be more helpful

Comment: @jafarpinjar updated answer.

Comment: what is $this->getQuote() here? need to inject any class?, then i am setting custom price for each item,

Comment: @jafarpinjar updated

Comment: hi @Sunil, so i need to replace only this line, $this->cart->addProduct($_product , $params); to $this->cart->getQuote()->addProduct($_product ,$params)

Comment: yes use my code and check it

Comment: Yes sure, I will use it after 1hr, doing some other work, thanks for the answer

Comment: have you tested it, custom price getting updated for both the products? in my case price for second product storing as 0

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I am updating custom price for bother the products, is it working in your case, when I add both products, price fr second product adding as 0

Comment: could you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62694678/active-an-extension-based-on-condition-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save the quote after adding product into the cart.

```
  $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();
```

after this line you can save the quote `$quote->save();` then you can get the `$quote->getId()`

Comment: hi @Keyur shaw, no if used that code, two products will not add to cart

Comment: What If you use `$this->cart->save();` after `$this->cart->addProduct` as Magento is also using the same @jafarpinjar

Comment: shaw, did you try the code, if used like that two products will not add to the cart

Comment: because, i am setting custom price for each product, cart->save() used inside for each means, price for second product getting as 0

Comment: price 0 means? you are getting quote id or not?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my code, pls chekc once

Comment: please update your answer else can you delete yours, since there is a answer to this, no one coming forward to asnwer

Comment: please delete your answer, that didn't help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this function:

```
public function execute()
{
    $selectedItems = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selectedItems');
    $selectedItems = explode(",", $selectedItems);
    try {

        $this->cart->save();
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        foreach ($selectedItems as $key => $selectedItem) {

            $params = array(
                'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                'product_id' => $selectedItem, //product Id
                'qty' => 1 //quantity of product                
            );
            $_product = $this->product->create()->load($selectedItem);
            $item = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($_product);
            if ($item) {
                $this->cart->updateItem($item->getId(), array('qty' => 1));
            } else {
                $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
            }
            $customPrice = 1000;
            $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();
            $quoteId = $quote->getId();
            $productItem = $this->getProductQuote($_product);
            $productItem->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
            $productItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
            $productItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            $insertProductSql = "INSERT INTO custom_table (quote_id, product_id) VALUES ('$quoteId', '$_product->getId()')";
            $connection->query($insertProductSql);
        }
        $this->cart->save();
        $status = 1;
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('%1', $e->getMessage()));
        $status = 0;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('error.'));
        $status = 0;
    }
    $result = array();
    $result['status'] = $status;
    $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
    $resultJson->setData($result);
    return $resultJson;
}
```

Comment: @Daneil, yes tried it, if $this->cart->save(); is used inside foreach, the custom price for next product is set to 0, that is why i used save() outside for each.

Comment: I have just updated the answer, please try again

Comment: this is adding only one product to the cart, not both

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about clone configurable product object when pass it to addProduct method

```
$this->_cart->addProduct(clone $product, $params);
```

It helps to add few simple products of one configurable.