# In magento2 how to override a add to cart button in both product list and product details page in custom module

Tags: magento-2.1

Product detail page:

[image]

Category Product list

[image]

> catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" template="Cm_Preorder::product/view/addtocart.phtml" />
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional" template="Cm_Preorder::product/view/addtocart.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Cm_Preorder" setup_version="1.0.1" schema_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>  
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Cm/Preorder/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Pre order'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       maxlength="12"
                       value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what issue ????

Comment: nothing comes add to  cart button does not change to pre order. its not override

Comment: check my answer and override .xml file like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> app/code/VendorName/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**OR**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" template="VendorName_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional" template="VendorName_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Make sure your module load after Magento_Catalog module. So add sequence in module.xml.

**[Update]**

Output:
[image]

Comment: I was follow your ways but it not working https://prnt.sc/nnta3s

Comment: hi @Sohel. I am adding product from ajax call, but quoteId not getting retrieved, here is my new question, can you help me please,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274172/quote-id-is-empty-when-inserting-multiple-records-into-cart-in-magento2

Comment: Did you add sequence tag in module.xml?

Comment: Check my edited question @sohel

Comment: @divyasekar check other module already overwrite this or not. Working fine with fresh magento installation. Check screenshot.

Comment: i will check and update you

Comment: @sohel you are wright it come under default magento luma theme https://prnt.sc/nnuy11   and not comes in my custom theme https://prnt.sc/nnv08u how to solve this issue

Comment: can you please help me to solve [this issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274740/how-to-add-a-out-of-stock-less-than-0-qty-product-product-into-cart-in-magento)

Answer (score 0):

> **module.xml :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> **app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

**Add This Code :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart"> //Product Detail Page
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_ModuleName::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional"> //Product Listing Page
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_ModuleName::product/list/items.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**For Listing Page Copy This File In To Your `product/list/items.phtml`:-**

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml
```

**For Product View Page Copy This File In To Your `product/view/addtocart.phtml`:-**

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

Comment: i want to override into my custom  module