# how to add negative qty product into cart in magento. 2

Tags: magento-2.1, product, cart, out-of-stock, qty

How to add a out of stock (less than 0 ) product in  shopping cart in magento 2

In my backorders setting  i have custom option as **Allow pre-order**  when  i  select a custom option and saved a backorder configuration  after that how to  add negative qty  product into cart  in magento.

**Product edit page in admin**

[image]

**Store > configuration > catalog > inventory**

[image]

I can't add a product into cart

[image]

Please some one help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockStateProvider">
        <plugin name="sr_custom_backorders"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\CatalogInventory\Model\StockStateProvider" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Suppose you custom option **Allow Pre-Order** value 5.

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/CatalogInventory/Model/StockStateProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\CatalogInventory\Model;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface;

class StockStateProvider
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockStateProvider $subject
     * @param $result
     * @param StockItemInterface $stockItem
     * @param $qty
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterCheckQty(
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockStateProvider $subject,
        $result,
        StockItemInterface $stockItem,
        $qty
    ) {
        if (!$result) {
            if ($stockItem->getQty() - $stockItem->getMinQty() - $qty < 0) {
                switch ($stockItem->getBackorders()) {
                    case \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock::BACKORDERS_YES_NONOTIFY:
                    case \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock::BACKORDERS_YES_NOTIFY:
                    case 5:
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**[Update]**

Using around plugin:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/CatalogInventory/Model/StockStateProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\CatalogInventory\Model;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface;

class StockStateProvider
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockStateProvider $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param StockItemInterface $stockItem
     * @param $qty
     * @return bool|mixed
     */
    public function aroundCheckQty(
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockStateProvider $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        StockItemInterface $stockItem,
        $qty
    ) {
        $result = $proceed($stockItem, $qty);
        if (!$result) {
            if ($stockItem->getQty() - $stockItem->getMinQty() - $qty < 0) {
                switch ($stockItem->getBackorders()) {
                    case \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock::BACKORDERS_YES_NONOTIFY:
                    case \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock::BACKORDERS_YES_NOTIFY:
                    case 5:
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Bootsgrid\Preorder\Plugin\CatalogInventory\Model\StockStateProvider::afterCheckQty() must implement interface Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface, none given, called in D:\wamp64\www\m2\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php on line 152 and defined in D:\wamp64\www\m2\magento\app\code\Cm\Preorder\Plugin\CatalogInventory\Model\StockStateProvider.php on line 15

Comment: It shows above error

Comment: What is your magento version?

Comment: Magento version is 2.1.3

Comment: Try using around plugin and remove generated dir.

Comment: ok i will try and update you

Comment: its working exactly what i m expected thank you so much

Comment: @SohelRana Sir I need a bit help of yours. can you please give me a bit of time

Comment: @AsadKhan what about?

Comment: @SohelRana Sir about https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274455/how-to-show-categories-in-system-xml-in-magento-2?noredirect=1#comment391832_274455 this problem can you please check it

Comment: Sorry @SohelRana this is not about this topic but I dont have any other root to access you thats why I comment here

Comment: can you please help me [solve this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275032/how-to-show-a-advance-inventory-custom-field-value-in-checkout-order-summary-in) @SohelRana sir

Answer (score 1):

```
Stroes -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory
```

**Click on Product stock Options Tab.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1 .Set `System - Configuration - Catalog - Inventory - Stock Options - Display Out of Stock Products to Yes.`

2.Set `System - Configuration - Catalog - Inventory - Product Stock Options - Backorder to Allow Qty Below 0.`