# How to show a advance inventory custom field value in checkout order summary in magento 2

Tags: magento2, inventory, checkout-page

How to  show a advance inventory custom field  value in  checkout order summary  in magento  2

Product edit page in admin

[image]

checkout page

[image]

code:

```
 <?php
namespace Cm\Preorder\Plugin\Checkout\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository as ProductRepository;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository;

class DefaultConfigProvider extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    protected $checkoutSession;

    protected $stockItem;

    protected $_productRepository;

    private $_objectManager;



    public function __construct(
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItem,
          \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->stockItem = $stockItem;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;

    }

    public function afterGetConfig(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, 
        array $result
    ) {
        $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];
        foreach ($items as $index => $item) {
            $quoteItem = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemById($item['item_id']);
            $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($quoteItem->getProduct()->getId());

            $productId = $product->getId();
            $stock = $this->stockItem->get($productId);
        /*    $preorder_note = $stock->getData('preorder_note'); */
            $result['quoteItemData'][$index]['preorder_note'] =$productId;
        }
        return $result;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository">
        <plugin name="checkout_item_sidebar"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Quote/Model/Cart/CartTotalRepository.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Quote\Model\Cart;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsItemExtensionFactory;

class CartTotalRepository
{
    /**
     * @var StockItemRepository
     */
    private $stockItemRepository;

    /**
     * @var CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $cartRepository;

    /**
     * @var TotalsItemExtensionFactory
     */
    private $extensionFactory;

    /**
     * CartTotalRepository constructor.
     *
     * @param StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository
     * @param CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository
     * @param TotalsItemExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository,
        CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository,
        TotalsItemExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
    ) {
        $this->stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
        $this->cartRepository = $cartRepository;
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
    }

    public function aroundGet(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $cartId
    ) {
        $quoteTotals = $proceed($cartId);
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->cartRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $quoteItemsArray = [];
        foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $index => $item) {
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            $stock = $this->getStockItem($productId);
            $quoteItemsArray[$item->getItemId()] = $stock;
        }
        $quoteItems = $quoteTotals->getItems();
        $items = [];

        /**  @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\Item $item */
        foreach ($quoteItems as $index => $item) {
            $extensionAttributes = $item->getExtensionAttributes();

            if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
                $extensionAttributes = $this->extensionFactory->create();
            }

            $preorderNote = '';
            if (isset($quoteItemsArray[$item->getItemId()])) {
                $preorderNote = $quoteItemsArray[$item->getItemId()]['preorder_note'];
            }

            $extensionAttributes->setPreorderNote($preorderNote);
            $item->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
            $items[$index] = $item;
        }

        $quoteTotals->setItems($items);
        return $quoteTotals;
    }

    /**
     * @param $productId
     * @return \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface
     */
    public function getStockItem($productId)
    {
        return $this->stockItemRepository->get($productId);
    }
}
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsItemInterface">
        <attribute code="preorder_note" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Now overwrite following class and add following code snippet

> magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html

```
<!-- ko if: $parent.extension_attributes -->
    <!-- ko if: $parent.extension_attributes.preorder_note -->
        <div data-bind="text: $parent.extension_attributes.preorder_note"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Now looks like:

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before_details') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<div class="product-item-details">

    <div class="product-item-inner">
        <div class="product-item-name-block">
            <strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="html: $parent.name"></strong>
            <div class="details-qty">
                <span class="label"><!-- ko i18n: 'Qty' --><!-- /ko --></span>
                <span class="value" data-bind="text: $parent.qty"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('after_details') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: $parent.extension_attributes -->
            <!-- ko if: $parent.extension_attributes.preorder_note -->
                <div data-bind="text: $parent.extension_attributes.preorder_note"></div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>

    <!-- ko if: (JSON.parse($parent.options).length > 0)-->
    <div class="product options" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active'}}">
        <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'View Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>
        <div data-role="content" class="content">
            <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
            <dl class="item-options">
                <!--ko foreach: JSON.parse($parent.options)-->
                <dt class="label" data-bind="text: label"></dt>
                    <!-- ko if: ($data.full_view)-->
                    <dd class="values" data-bind="html: full_view"></dd>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko ifnot: ($data.full_view)-->
                    <dd class="values" data-bind="text: value"></dd>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('item_message') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

***Clear cache and empty generated directory.***

Comment: ok sir i will try it and update you.

Comment: Its come like this https://prnt.sc/nq4076

Comment: This is not related to this changes.

Comment: if i  comment the di.xml type   after run the site its shows https://prnt.sc/nq43gl

Comment: if i uncomment the di.xml  type  its shows https://prnt.sc/nq4076

Comment: what is your magento version? Working fine with 2.2, 2.3

Comment: magento version is 2.1.3

Comment: Change the plugin after to around. Check the updated answer.

Comment: after update a code its still shows in shopping cart page https://prnt.sc/nq4obz  and checkout page  prnt.sc/nq4076

Comment: Not sure why not working in your side. Can you check with fresh installation?

Comment: i will check with fresh installation magento version 2.1.3

Comment: I have this issue Cannot read property "quoteData" of undefined (quote.js)
Cannot read property 'storeCode' of undefined (url-builder.js)
Cannot convert undefined or null to object (customer-addresses.js) under shopping cart page  https://prnt.sc/nq50nh

Comment: This is not problem with this answer. I can't reproduce 2.1.3, 2.1.16, 2.2, 2.3.1. Don't how you change

Comment: can you help me to solve [this issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275406/how-to-get-a-simple-product-id-from-configurable-option-in-magento-2)

Comment: I have done  by above code @Sohel Rana can you  please help  me  to get a  simple product id from configurable in checkout order summary  [please refer this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275932/how-to-get-a-simple-product-id-from-configurable-in-checkout-order-summary-in-ma)

Comment: can you please help me to solve [this issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279263/how-to-add-a-custom-customer-attributes-in-checkout-register-page-in-magento2) sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="add_product_datails"
         type="NameSpace\ModuleName\Plugin\Model\DefaultConfigProvider"/>
    </type>


 public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, $result)
{ 
      $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];
    foreach ($items as $index => $item) {
   $result['quoteItemData'][$index]['your_mesage_key'] = $yourmessage;
}
}
```

> into that summary.phtml
>
> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html

```
<!-- ko if: (getMessage($parents[1]))-->
        <span class="product-view-approveditem-check-icon">
            <span class="label" data-bind="text: getMessage($parents[1]"></span>
        </span>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

> details.js

```
getMessage: function (itemId) {
                var itemsData = window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData;
                var msg= '';
                itemsData.forEach(function(item) {
                    if (item.item_id == itemId['item_id']) {
                        msg= item.is_show_icon;
                    }
                });
            return msg;
            },
```

Comment: its not working  its still loading