# How to show a advance inventory custom field value in sales order view page in frontend and backend in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order-view

How to show a advance inventory custom field value in sales order view page  in frontend and backend  in magento 2

Product edit page in admin

[image]

Frontend:

[image: t e]

Backend:

[image: i]

please someone can me help for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display product attributes in order history items and admin panel you need to create extra column in `sales_order_item` table.

**STEP1**: In your `Vendor\Module\Setup\UpgradeSchema.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * Upgrades DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $orderTable = 'sales_order_item';

        //Order table
        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($orderTable),
                'preorder_note',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Product pre order'
                ]
            );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**STEP2**: Create plugin to save the pre order value in `sales_order_items` table.
In you `di.xml` create a plugin.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem">
        <plugin name="unique_name" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ToOrderItem" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

`Vendor\Module\Plugin\ToOrderItem.php`

```
 <?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem as QuoteToOrderItem;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;


class ToOrderItem
{
    /*
    * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    */
    protected $productRepository;
    protected $stockItem;


    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
         \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItem
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->stockItem = $stockItem;
    }

    /**
     * aroundConvert
     *
     * @param QuoteToOrderItem $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item
     */
    public function aroundConvert(
        QuoteToOrderItem $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $item,
        $data = []
    ) {
        $orderItem = $proceed($item, $data);
        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($orderItem->getProduct()->getId());

        if(!empty($product->getId())) {

        $productStock = $this->stockItem->get($product->getId());
        $preorder= $productStock->getData('preorder'); 

            // $product->getPreOrder() is product attribute
            $orderItem->setPreOrder($preorder);
        }
        return $orderItem;
    }
}
```

**STEP3**: To display pre order notes in front end order history, override  `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/templates/order/items/renderer/default.phtml` you can call pre order value of ordered items by

```
$_item->getPreorder();
```

**STEP4**: To display this in admin panel override sales_order_view.xml in `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml` and you can see this block override this block template with your custom template.  Hope you know how to override a xml file template.

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name" name="column_name" template="Magento_Sales::items/column/name.phtml" group="column"/>
```

In your custom template copy all the code in `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml` to your custom template and add 
`$_item->getPreorder();` 
this line of code to display the pre order notes in admin panel where you want.

**STEP5:** To display in sales order grid create `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top"/>
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="preorder_notes" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Sales\OrderItems">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Pre order</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

`Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Sales\OrderItems.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Sales;


use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;

class OrderItems extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    protected $orderInterface;
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $orderInterface,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ){
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->_orderInterface = $orderInterface;
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $orderId = $item['increment_id'];
                $orderObj = $this->_orderInterface->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
                $result = '';
                foreach ($orderObj->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
                    $result .= $orderItem->getPreorder().', ';
                }
                $item['preorder_notes'] = $result;
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

It will display comma separated when the order has multiple order items

Comment: value does save in sales_order_item

Comment: What is your pre-order attribute code?

Comment: <attribute code="preorder_note" type="string"/>

Comment: its working, typo mistake done by me

Comment: Please check ToOrderItem.php edits match with your file.

Comment: hmmm.....Okie....:-)

Comment: how to show a sales_order_item in  sales order grid  in admin can you please help me  @Ranganathan

Comment: give me some mins to work around......`sales_order_item` means item name? or something else?

Comment: ok sure thank you

Comment: sales_order_item means item name? or something else?

Comment: $_item->getPreorder();

Comment: If there is more than one order item, then it should be?

Comment: in sales_order_item i added a column 'preorder'  now i need to show preorder  in sales_order_grid in admin

Comment: Updated pls check now

Comment: i will check and update you

Comment: its giving a blank value

Comment: I think the issue from ` $orderObj = $this->_orderInterface->loadByIncrementId($orderId);` this line..try to get order items by another way

Comment: ok i will try it

Comment: ok...let me know once done

Comment: its shows --> https://prnt.sc/nqvsuo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93852/discussion-between-ranganathan-and-divya-sekar).

Comment: in sales_order_item  table ->https://prnt.sc/nqvtsy  i have a backorder  field. and the the code is -> https://prnt.sc/nqvv1t   and https://prnt.sc/nqvveo  and in admin grid show blanks https://prnt.sc/nqvsuo

Comment: Ahh found an issue.... there is a typo mistake in https://prnt.sc/nqvveo this...`backorders` not `backoreders`

Comment: ya yes its working now thank you  so much @Ranganathan

Comment: welcome..@divya

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93883/discussion-on-answer-by-ranganathan-how-to-show-a-advance-inventory-custom-field).

Comment: Can you please help me solve [this issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275032/how-to-show-a-advance-inventory-custom-field-value-in-checkout-order-summary-in/275102?noredirect=1#comment392018_275102)

Comment: Today i can't....will check and let u know tmrw

Comment: i have a one issue the above code  for simple product preorder show  a value fine in sales_order_grid but not  working for configurable simple product  https://prnt.sc/ns7yd2 , https://prnt.sc/ns7yxy i want to show a backorder  value 3 in sales _order_grid  but it show a configurable product type backorder value 0 in sales_order_grid  https://prnt.sc/ns800w

Comment: What is the value showing in order view page? configurable product value or simple product value ?

Comment: I have edited my answer.....pls double check before use it...