# How to get a simple product id from configurable option in magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

How to get a simple product id from configurable option in magento 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to override block:

> app/code/Custom/Coreoverride/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable" type="Custom\Coreoverride\Block\Swatches\Product\Renderer\Configurable"/>
</config>
```

> app/code/Custom/Coreoverride/Block/ConfigurableProduct/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php

```
    <?php

namespace Custom\Coreoverride\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Type;

use Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\DecoderInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;

/**
 * Class Configurable
 *
 * @package Custom\Coreoverride\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Type
 */
class Configurable
{
    /**
     * @var EncoderInterface
     */
    protected $jsonEncoder;

    /**
     * @var DecoderInterface
     */
    protected $jsonDecoder;

    /**
     * @var StockRegistryInterface
     */
    protected $stockRegistry;

    /**
     * Configurable constructor.
     * @param EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
     * @param DecoderInterface $jsonDecoder
     * @param StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
     */
    public function __construct(
        EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        DecoderInterface $jsonDecoder,
        StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
    ) {
        $this->jsonDecoder = $jsonDecoder;
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * backorders status, backorders time period
     *
     * @param \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @return array
     */
    public function aroundGetJsonConfig(
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $config = $proceed();
        $config = $this->jsonDecoder->decode($config);
        foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $product) {
                echo $product->getId();
        }
        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($config);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to get a  configurable product id in addtocart template file