# how to add a custom customer attributes under shipping address in checkout page in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer-attribute

how to add a custom customer attributes under shipping address in checkout  page in Magento2?

i m using [this extension](https://marketplace.magento.com/clarion-customer-attribute.html) for customer attributes.

In customer registration page

[image]

In Shipping Page

[image]

Comment: can you please where you are looking for the custom attribute.

Comment: i already have a customer attribute in customer registration page https://prnt.sc/o57l4c

Comment: now i need  a customer  attribute in checkout register page

Comment: have you tried  `$usedInForms = array(
            'checkout_register',
        );` in installData

Comment: i tried this its not works

Comment: @divyasekar check this reference 1: : https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-add-extra-billing-or-shipping-field-to-the-checkout/ ,  reference 2: https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-ExtraCheckoutAddressFields

Comment: this will help you https://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/

Comment: what's the point of linking an extension here? If you are using an extension and it works, why ask the question? If it doesn't work, why mention it?

Comment: i need to enhance this  extension  here that while i m asking a question, by using this extension dynamic customer attributes show the fields in the customer account create  and customer account edit page  i need to enhance  the dynamic customer attributes fields to shown in checkout page also

Comment: @rakesh  your link  shows static field displayed in the checkout page

Comment: https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-custom-field-in-address-form-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

step1 : try to create a plugin for the
`\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor::process` method. because billing and shipping address forms are generated dynamically.

`app/code/Adamsmage/Customattribute/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="add_custom_field_checkout_form" type="Adamsmage\Customattribute\Model\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

step2 : Create plugin class on this Directory.

`app\code\Adamsmage\Customattribute\Model\Plugin\Checkout`

```
<?php
namespace Adamsmage\Customattribute\Model\Plugin\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['custom_field'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                'options' => [],
                'id' => 'custom-field'
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.custom_field',
            'label' => 'Checkout Custom Field',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => 250,
            'id' => 'custom-field'
        ];


        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: it will add a static field but i need to ad a  dynamic field in checkout page